# How to change position of image in bootstrap column vertically by a few pixels

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered and I'm too much of a noob to apply to my specific situation.

My goal is to move the two images in below *screenshot example* so that they align with the grey background instead of sitting partially on top of the banner image.  Basically I just want to move them down 10-20 pixels or so.

Happy to provide additional information as needed.

**Screenshot example:**

https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/example.png

**Homepage:**

https://etractorimplements.com/

**Code:**

```
<section class="feature_sec">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="page-width">
<div class="collection-grid-items">
<div class="grid-service">
<div class="col-md-3 hidden-akk col-sm-4  wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".7s">
<div class="widget-images slide-service ">
<a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/rotary-tillers/"> <img  data-src="https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/heavy-duty-rotary-tiller-small.jpg" class="img-responsive lazy" alt="Rotary Tiller Heavy Duty" > </a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="service-grid col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".1s">
<div class="service service_1 row"> <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i><!--<i class="zmdi zmdi-money-box"></i>-->
<?php dynamic_sidebar('widget1home');?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="service-grid col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".3s">
<div class="service service-2 row"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <!--<i class="zmdi zmdi-time zmdi-hc-fw"></i>-->
<?php dynamic_sidebar('widget2home');?>
</div>
</div>
<!--  <div class="service-grid col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">                <div class="service service-2 row"> <i class="zmdi zmdi-thumb-up"></i>                  <?php //dynamic_sidebar('widget3home');?>               </div>              </div> -->
<div class="col-md-3 hidden-akk col-sm-3 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".7s">
<div class="widget-images slide-service ">
<a href="https://etractorimplements.com/product-category/rotary-tillers/"> <img  data-src="https://etractorimplements.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/heavy-duty-rotary-tiller-side-shift-small.jpg" class="img-responsive lazy" alt="Heavy Duty Rotary Tiller with Side Shift"> </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can be guided by this answer: [Bootstrap DIV](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148792/c%C3%B3mo-ajustar-una-imagen-a-un-div-donde-la-imagen-es-m%C3%A1s-grande-que-el-div-css)

Comment: @FernandoValderramaGuayán thanks for your suggestion however I unfortunately am still having trouble figuring out how to apply to my specific situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, the structure of your HTML elements needs some changes. It's a rule of thumb that only `col` should be direct child of `row`. So if you want for example two images next to each other on one line, you should do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img ... >
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img ... >
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, to move those images lower, you can either set margin to `row` inline using Bootstrap class `mt-5` (margin top 5. note that 5 is maximum using Bootstrap classes). If this margin won't be enough, you can safely create multiple empty `row` with `mt-5` to create extra space on top. OR same, just using CSS.

At the end your HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
<div class="row mt-5">
<div class="row mt-5">
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img ... >
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <img ... >
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding)

[In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)